# Use $\nabla\times(f \vec A)=\nabla f \times \vec A + f (\nabla \times \vec A)$ to rewrite Faraday's law as $\omega \vec B_0=\vec k \times \vec E_0$

Tags: proof-verification, physics, electromagnetism

> We may represent a general electromagnetic plane wave by (real part of the complex exponentials):
>   $$\vec E = \vec E_0\exp(i\vec k \cdot \vec r - i \omega t) \quad\text{&}\quad\vec B = \vec B_0\exp(i\vec k \cdot \vec r - i \omega t)$$
>   Show that Faraday's law $$\partial_t \vec B=-\nabla \times \vec E\tag{1}$$ becomes $$\omega \vec B_0=\vec k \times \vec E_0\tag{2}$$

I know I can write 
$$\partial_t \vec B=-i \omega\exp(i\vec k \cdot \vec r - i \omega t)\vec B_0$$ for the LHS of $(1)$

Letting $f=\exp(i\vec k \cdot \vec r - i \omega t)$ then $\partial_t \vec B=-i \omega f \vec B_0$ and $\vec E = f \vec E_0$ and the RHS of $(1)$ is
$$\begin{align} -\nabla \times \vec E &=-\left(\nabla\times(f \vec E_0)\right)\\&=-\left(\nabla f \times \vec E_0 + f (\nabla \times \vec E_0)\right)\\&=-\left(i f\vec k \times  \vec E_0+f(\nabla \times \vec E_0)\right)\end{align}$$

The only way I can reach $(2)$ is iff  $$\nabla \times \vec E_0=\vec 0$$ which would be the case under the assumption that $\vec E_0$ and $\vec B_0$ are constant vectors.

The question did not stipulate this and in the answer there is no mention of it:

[image: answer]

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: A simple yes or no will suffice

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct.

Comment: It all depends on what is meant by a plane wave. To my knowledge, plane waves have constant polarization and constant amplitude (both contained in $\vec{E}_0$), but I don't know for sure